# Snap drawn rectangle to grid

Tags: c#, winforms, grid, picturebox

I have the below which draws a rectangle on mouse drag and also a grid drawing script which draws a 32x32 grid on the picture box what I'm trying to do is snap the rectangle to the grid then screen shot inside the rectangle.

I've got the screen shot bit and the drawing of the rectangle just not the snapping to grid bit working.

```
private bool _selecting;
private Rectangle _selection;

private void picCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        _selecting = true;
        _selection = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X, e.Y), new Size());
    }
}

private void picCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_selecting)
    {
        _selection.Width = e.X - _selection.X;
        _selection.Height = e.Y - _selection.Y;

        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
}

public Image Crop(Image image, Rectangle selection)
{
    Bitmap bmp = image as Bitmap;

    // Check if it is a bitmap:
    if (bmp == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("No valid bitmap");

    // Crop the image:
    Bitmap cropBmp = bmp.Clone(selection, bmp.PixelFormat);

    // Release the resources:
    image.Dispose();

    return cropBmp;
}

private void picCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left &&
        _selecting &&
        _selection.Size != new Size())
    {
        // Create cropped image:
        //Image img = Crop(pictureBox1.Image, _selection);

        // Fit image to the picturebox:
        //pictureBox1.Image = img;

        _selecting = false;
    }
    else
        _selecting = false;
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (_selecting)
    {
        // Draw a rectangle displaying the current selection
        Pen pen = Pens.GreenYellow;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _selection);
    }

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    int numOfCells = amount;
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.LightGray);

    for (int y = 0; y < numOfCells; ++y)
    {
        g.DrawLine(p, 0, y * ysize, numOfCells * ysize, y * ysize);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < numOfCells; ++x)
    {
        g.DrawLine(p, x * xsize, 0, x * xsize, numOfCells * xsize);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any snapping to grid code. How could it possibly work?

Comment: Are you asking how the abstract idea of "snapping" a window would work? I would declare a `snapPadDist` and if the value of the mouse when dragging is within `snapPadDist` of the target rectangle, then just draw the rectangle the same size as the target rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would declare a snapping method

```
private Point SnapToGrid(Point p)
{
    double x = Math.Round((double)p.X / xsize) * xsize;
    double y = Math.Round((double)p.Y / ysize) * ysize;
    return new Point((int)x, (int)y);
}
```

Then you can initialize the selection like this in MouseDown:

```
_selection = new Rectangle(SnapToGrid(e.Location), new Size());
```

And you can adjust the width in MouseMove like this:

```
Point dest = SnapToGrid(e.Location);
_selection.Width = dest.X - _selection.X;
_selection.Height = dest.Y - _selection.Y;
```